# Assign id from foreign table to current table laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel eloquent to get the query results. I have two tables below:

users table:

```
|  id | department_id
|  1  |   1
|  2  |   3
|  3  |   2
```

department table:

```
| id  |  name
| 1   | A
| 2   | B
| 3   | C
| 4   | D
| 5   | E
```

How to get one unassigned ID, not existing department ID, into the users table? Example, 4 & 5 are not yet existing in users table, so how can I get 4 or 5 using an eloquent?

I am thinking of this but this is not correct.

```
Department::select('department.id as id')
             ->leftJoin('users', 'users.department_id' ,'department.id')
             ->pluck('id');
```

Does anybody know?

Comment: did you not setup relationships between the models?

Comment: 1:1 relationship. 1 user can have one department only.

Comment: did you define them on the model? can you show the relationship methods

Comment: provided that methods are not yet created. thanks,.

Comment: if you got 4,5  both in return is it ok for you 
as per your question unassigned department why you want only one unassigned department

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh I just need only one department ID. I used "4 or 5" from my question.

Comment: @smzapp there are many unassigned id's so in return  id's will be multiple

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh yeah, I understand. That's the problem I need to solve using eloquent. Just one department ID is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe below code will work for you :

```
Department::select('department.id as id')
               ->whereNotIn('id', User::whereNotNull('department_id')->pluck('department_id'))
             ->pluck('id');
```

Comment: This returns an empty result. I guess the problem is in ` $query->select('DISTINCT department_id')
                  ->from('users');   `

Comment: [https://prnt.sc/vieelu](https://prnt.sc/vieelu)
this is working fine my side

Comment: if I use whereIn, there are results found but not on whereNotIn

Comment: @smzapp try this one

$dep_ids = Users::pluck('department_id')->toArray();

$user = Department::whereNotIn('id',$dep_ids)->get();

Comment: I got this solution. Thanks for the help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816311/7067321

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 //here you first got all the department which is assigned to user

  $assigned_dept = Users::pluck('department_id')->toArray(); 
  $department = array_values($assigned_dept); //output:['1','3','2']
  
  //here you can select department which is not assigned to user with limit
  $user = Department::whereNotIn('id',$department)
                      ->limit(1)->get();
```

hope it works for you..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```php
Department::whereNotIn('id', User::pluck('department_id'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answers others, there is a problem with the array if department_id is NULL. So, I added whereNotNull and also last() and then the problem is solved. Let me post the answer here:

```
Department::select('department.id as id')
   ->whereNotIn('id', User::whereNotNull('department_id')->pluck('department_id'))
   ->pluck('id')
   ->last();  // since I only need one row
```